# multiple javascript functions in rshiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

How do you have multiple javascript functions in RShiny? I'm combining example 1 and 2 from this example [https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/extendShinyjs.html#:~:text=Any%20JavaScript%20function%20defined%20in%20your%20script%20that,can%20call%20it%20from%20R%20with%20js%24myfunc%20%28%29](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/extendShinyjs.html#:%7E:text=Any%20JavaScript%20function%20defined%20in%20your%20script%20that,can%20call%20it%20from%20R%20with%20js%24myfunc%20%28%29).

```
jsCode <- '
    shinyjs.backgroundCol = function(params) {
      var defaultParams = {
        id : null,
        col : "red"
      };
      params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);

      var el = $("#" + params.id);
      el.css("background-color", params.col);
    }'
jsCode <- "shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){$('body').css('background', params);}"
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("backgroundCol")),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("pageCol")),
    selectInput("col", "Colour:",
                c("white", "yellow", "red", "blue", "purple"))
    p(id = "name", "My name is Dean"),
    p(id = "sport", "I like soccer"),
    selectInput("col", "Colour",
                c("green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "white")),
    selectInput("selector", "Element", c("sport", "name", "button")),
    actionButton("button", "Go")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      js$backgroundCol(input$selector, input$col)
    })
    observeEvent(input$col, {
      js$pageCol(input$col)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
    shinyjs.backgroundCol = function(params) {
      var defaultParams = {
        id : null,
        col : "red"
      };
      params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
      var el = $("#" + params.id);
      el.css("background-color", params.col);};
    shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){$("body").css("background", params);};'

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("backgroundCol", "pageCol")),
    selectInput("pageCol", "Page colour",
                c("green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "white")),
    hr(),
    selectInput("selector", "Element", c("sport", "name", "button")),
    selectInput("backgroundColSelect", "Background colour:",
                c("yellow", "white", "red", "blue", "purple")),
    p(id = "name", "My name is Dean"),
    p(id = "sport", "I like soccer"),
    actionButton("button", "Go")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      js$backgroundCol(input$selector, input$backgroundColSelect)
      js$pageCol(input$pageCol)
    })
  }
)
```